# running a second odoo instance on ubuntu gives "Peer authentication failed for user" error in database

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, odoo

i am running an odoo instance on port 8069 with database user odoo. Now i am trying to run another instance on a different port. So i created a new postgres user named  project .Below is my odoo conf file.

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = myadmin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = project
db_password = False
addons_path =/opt/odoo/proj/odoo/addons/,/opt/odoo/proj/custom_addons/
log_level = info
logfile = /var/log/odoo/proj-server.log
log_handler = ["[':INFO']"]
xmlrpc_port = 8070
```

I am getting Internal server error and my log says **"psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "project" - - -.
"** I understand that something is wrong with the new user project, that i created. How should i make changes to the new user so that the error gets fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The database logon is denied to your new user by the rules in PostgreSQL [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), given the empty `db_host` (local connection through Unix domain sockets) and `db_password` (passwordless connection)

What's needed:

- figure out what security policy should apply to that user: from where is it allowed to connect, to which database(s), and whether a password is required.
- edit `pg_hba.conf` accordingly.
- edit the Odoo options `db_host` and `db_password` accordingly.
- reload the postgresql service.